# How to import CSV into MySQL with fields separated by commas and also contain commas but no enclosers

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I have a CSV file but the strings within the fields contain commas. There are no enclosures within the fields to distinguish the fields from the commas.

i.e.:
Sat Apr 20 14:50:47 CDT 2013,twitter_handle,News 'SURPRISE': Blah blah 'Stuff,' People Say http://link.to/something,,

I've been reading through LOAD DATA INFILE but I'm not seeing anything to help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If data fields that contain a comma are not properly quoted, there is no way that any computer program can decide which commas are intended as field separators and which are part of the data itself.

Speak to the source of your CSV file and ask them to either use proper quoting, or use a separator that will not appear in a data field (e.g. tab separator).

Comment: Data scrubbing like this causes no end of frustration and time that could be better spent :-(  One thought: In your example, the only field that looks like it could have extra commas is the last one.  If that is the case, you could actually pre-process the data to fix the issue.  If more than one field could have data-commas, you cannot do that.  Is that the case?

Comment: That is the case. Its just the last field. I was trying to think of a way to define three columns with the first two fields defined by the comma, and the third column would just accept whatever was left over in the string.

Comment: I ended up using Python to read the csv and write a new one. I iterated through the records and concatenated any extra existing array values beyond the first two array values.

Comment: Glad you were able to do that.  If this answer solved your problem, don't forget to accept it.